# Eigen library, Jacobi SVD

Tags: c++, c++11, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm trying to estimate a 3D rotation matrix between two sets of points, and I want to do that by computing the SVD of the covariance matrix, say `C`, as follows:

```
U,S,V = svd(C)
R = V * U^T
```

`C` in my case is `3x3` . I am using the Eigen's JacobiSVD module for this and I only recently found out that it stores matrices in column-major format. So that has had me confused.

So, when using Eigen, should I do:
`V*U.transpose()` or `V.transpose()*U` ?

Additionally, the rotation is accurate upto changing the sign of the column of U corresponding to the smallest singular value,such that determinant of R is positive. Let's say the index of the smallest singular value is `minIndex` .

So when the determinant is negative, because of the column major confusion, should I do:

`U.col(minIndex) *= -1 or U.row(minIndex) *= -1`

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you really should write some unit tests for this. How else would you verify _any_ answer? Moreover, how else would the next developer be convinced that your code is correct?

Comment: Singular values are always positive (more precisely: non-negative). The determinant of `U` is negative, if it represents a reflection instead of a rotation (both are unitary matrices, and that is all what `svd` guarantees). If you have a symmetric matrix `C`, why do you compute the SVD instead of using `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`? How do you compute `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with matrices being stored row-major or column major. `svd(C)` gives you:

```
U * S.asDiagonal() * V.transpose() == C
```

so the closest rotation `R` to `C` is:

```
R = U * V.transpose();
```

If you want to apply `R` to a point `p` (stored as column-vector), then you do:

```
q = R * p;
```

Now whether you are interested `R` or its inverse `R.transpose()==V.transpose()*U` is up to you.

The singular values scale the columns of `U`, so you should invert the columns to get `det(U)=1`. Again, nothing to do with storage layout.